# Lock a folder but access its files from VBA in windows 7

Tags: excel, directory, protected

I have created an Excel tool which runs program files saved in a particular folder.
But I need to protect this folder and still be able to access these files while the VBA program is running.
How do I accomplish it?

Comment: any answers? plz share something that can at least get me started on this

Comment: I'm in the same boat right now. I'm interested to see if anyone has any advice. I'll take a look around.

Comment: How do you protect the folder? By using windows permissions. So if windows user Joe Bloggs doesn't have access to the files through explorer, he also doesn't have access to the files while running Excel. You could Run-As the Excel file to be a different user or you could use some connect code inside your VBA but either way you need to hard code a login/password that has access

Comment: The way this is normally done is with a service in the middle that contains authorisation. Joe Bloggs connects to the service inside Excel and the service does the work on behalf of Joe (as a different user). It's unlikely that this is suitable for you though. Perhaps you could add some more background

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access Excel files in that folder, instead of locking the folder, you can lock all of the Excel files and open them using the `Workbook.Open` Method documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195811(office.11).aspx) as it allows you to pass a password as an argument.